# Extract equal values for multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, fetch, key

I have this problem. I have a multidimensional json array (don't ask - legacy code). I convert it to PHP array. I need to extract all KEYS that have EQUAL VALUE (in my case "666"). I need each key to be assign to a SEPARATE variable. In my code I succeeded to fetch the keys but I can assign them only to another array or all at once to a single variable. Please HELP!!!

Love V

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//user input
$in = "666";

$outputZ = '[
{"record_id_001":"1"},
{"record_id_002":"13"},
{"record_id_003":"666"},
{"record_id_004":"72661781"},
{"record_id_005":"8762"},
{"record_id_006":"666"},
{"record_id_007":"8762"},
{"record_id_008":"666"},
{"record_id_009":"8762"},
{"record_id_010":"8762"},
{"record_id_011":"666"}
]';

//convert json to php array
//someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
$decoZ = json_decode($outputZ, true);

// TESTING (move to comment latter)
//print_r ($decoZ);

//loop through each array an check for user input
//way 1: assign to new array
foreach($decoZ as $array => $number)
foreach($number as $key => $value)
    if (in_array("$in", $number)) {
        $var = $key;
        $getarray = "'" . $var . "'";
        $recnumber = array($getarray);
        print_r ($recnumber);
        }

//way 2: assign to variable 
foreach($decoZ as $array => $number)
foreach($number as $key => $value)
    if (in_array("$in", $number)) {
        $var = $key;
        echo "$var" . " ";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwritting your array on each iterations `$recnumber = array($getarray);`

I would rather follow this logic :

```
<?php
//user input
$in = "666";

$outputZ = '[
{"record_id_001":"1"},
{"record_id_002":"13"},
{"record_id_003":"666"},
{"record_id_004":"72661781"},
{"record_id_005":"8762"},
{"record_id_006":"666"},
{"record_id_007":"8762"},
{"record_id_008":"666"},
{"record_id_009":"8762"},
{"record_id_010":"8762"},
{"record_id_011":"666"}
]';

$decoZ = json_decode($outputZ, true);


// create empty array
$recnumber = [];
foreach($decoZ as $record)
{
    foreach($record as $key => $value)
    {
        // simply compare input with current value
        if ($value === $in)
        {
            // add the key to the previously created array
            $recnumber[] = $key;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($recnumber);
```

This outputs :

> array(4) {
> [0]=>
> string(13) "record_id_003"
> [1]=>
> string(13) "record_id_006"
> [2]=>
> string(13) "record_id_008"
> [3]=>
> string(13) "record_id_011"
> }

Comment: Thanks @Cid, that's almost all I needed, but I need to proceed the keys further, so I need to assign all Values from this new Array to a variables. How can I do this? (There will be no fixed number of results - from 2 to 5). Thanks

Comment: Dynamically created variables, like `$record_id_003`, `$record_id_006` and so on?

Comment: Yes, I need to proceed them, cause they are an ids in the database and I need to extract only those records, so I need them as $something...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remap the records.

At the end you can grab them like

```
$codes666 = $ids['666'];
```

```
$outputZ = '[
{"record_id_001":"1"},
{"record_id_002":"13"},
{"record_id_003":"666"},
{"record_id_004":"72661781"},
{"record_id_005":"8762"},
{"record_id_006":"666"},
{"record_id_007":"8762"},
{"record_id_008":"666"},
{"record_id_009":"8762"},
{"record_id_010":"8762"},
{"record_id_011":"666"}
]';

$records = json_decode($outputZ);
$ids = [];
foreach($records as $record) {
    foreach($record as $key => $value) {
        $ids[(string)$value][] = $key;
    }
}

print_r($ids);
```

Gives

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => record_id_001
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => record_id_002
        )

    [666] => Array
        (
            [0] => record_id_003
            [1] => record_id_006
            [2] => record_id_008
            [3] => record_id_011
        )

    [72661781] => Array
        (
            [0] => record_id_004
        )

    [8762] => Array
        (
            [0] => record_id_005
            [1] => record_id_007
            [2] => record_id_009
            [3] => record_id_010
        )

)
```